# Why is my personal website's homepage not displayed until I "repeat the search with the omitted results included"?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

I have a website which is essentially just a blog and a link to my CV. When I google my name the CV is at the top of all the search results. However, the homepage of my website doesn't show up at all.

In fact, I have to click "repeat the search with the omitted results included" on the last page of Google to see the page at all. When I do this, the homepage is then the third result.

How do I tell Google to list the homepage as the main page that should be returned when I search my name, and for the CV to be after, or even omitted?

Comment: To be able to answer this question, we'd need to know what you have on your home page.  What is your site?  What do you have on your home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds to me like an SEO thing. Google probably doesn't deem the front page to be important/unique enough to give a first-class search result.

Here are some tips, in order of how easy they are:

1. Make sure every page on your site links back to the home page in the header. Internal link counts help Google understand the most important pages on your site.
2. Make sure your home page has at least a little bit of content, like a few sentences at minimum, to help Google's ML algorithms have something to go on as far as page topic, and to differentiate it from other pages. It should also be easy for someone to drill down to any other page on your site by starting from the home page.
3. Build quality backlinks to your website to increase its weight in search. Along with (1), this will give your home page high weight on your website.